# PHP 5 Digit Code Generation?

Tags: php, loops

Can Some body will help me how can I genrete 5 digit code like if I have a code Like

```
00001
00002
.
.
.
00009
```

and then after this it should come back like below
    00019
    .
    .
    99999

Please can somebody help me which type of loop I have to do to increment forward and decrements backward.

Many thanks

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php Sprintf could be of use to you ;-)

Comment: (a) Where do you decrement? (b) All loops are essentially the same. Every loop can be expressed as `while` loop. The difference is just for convenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [**`str_pad()`**](http://www.php.net/str_pad) to produce a string of constant length, padded by zeros on the left :

```
for ($i=1 ; $i<10000 ; $i++) {
    echo str_pad($i, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '<br />';
}
```

And, to go backwards, just change the starting value, condition, and use a decrement in your for loop :

```
for ($i=99999 ; $i>0 ; $i--) {
    echo str_pad($i, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: it worked great but it produced the exact code using `for ($i=0 ; $i<10000 ; $i++) {
    echo str_pad($i, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '<br />';
}`  to 09999 I just need 99999 instead. you can help me sure.

Comment: Instead of looping until 10000 you should loop until 100000 then ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
str_pad(mt_rand(1,99999),"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

[Working Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/a4eoHH)

Answer (score 1):

You mean:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 100000; $i++)
  echo str_pad($i, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
for ($i = 99999; $i > 0; $i--)
  echo str_pad($i '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

?

Comment: Actually I have to store this in DB like State Identifier with NY00001 to NY00002 and so on the number should always be in 5 digit. in this range like 00001 start to 99999 end. Please help me.

Comment: I really try to understand what you mean, but I'm not sure. If you need an incrementing id in a database, you should use an auto_increment field. This has nothing to do with the loop. Try to break up your problem in separate pieces. These smaller problems will be easier to solve by you or by the people here on SO.

Comment: The numbers are always 5 digits.

Comment: I'm storing a pruduct reference number purchased from NewYork. So if a product is purchased from NewYork then it's Code would be NY00001 for product 1 in the db without any auto increment field. it must be unique and then fro product like NY99999 will be last one that'll be stored.